# Manually compile OpenSSL: symbol can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: linker, openssl

My OpenSSL seems to be too old. And there's no place where they explain how to install a more recent OpenSSL library.

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
built on: Fri Mar 30 13:47:53 2018
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

When I want to manually install a more recent OpenSSL library, I get this error:

```
root@mycomputer:/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o# ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib

[...compile stuff...]

make[3]: Entering directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o'
make[4]: Entering directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o'
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(rsaz_exp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' 
    can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libcrypto.a(rsaz_exp.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [link_a.gnu] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o'
make[3]: *** [do_linux-shared] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o'
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.so.1.0.0] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o'
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/install/openssl-1.0.2o/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you have the required development packages for openssl installed  ? And what version is your openssl package ? You need to state your operating system if you need help figuring that out.

Comment: @nos Thanks for your suggestion, added more details

Comment: Can you delete `crypto/bn/rsaz_exp.o`, do `make` again, look at the output and copy and post the actual command used to compile that file?

Comment: Or did you happen to do another `make` run previously, with different configuration options and without properly cleaning in between (with `make distclean`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(rsaz_exp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' 
    can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

is saying that the object file `rsaz_exp.o` in the archive `libcrypto.a`
has not been compiled as Position Independent Code, and it must be to be
linked into a shared object. It suggests you recompile that object file with
`-fPIC`. Which would mean rebuilding your `libcrypto.a` from source, with
the `-fPIC` compilation option.

If you don't want to do that, provide your linkage with a shared `libcrypto.so`
to link against instead.

Comment: My ssh lib is too old for Python 3.7, I've compiled it manually and now when I launch program using ssh, like nginx, I get this error: `/usr/sbin/nginx: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)`

Comment: @OlivierPons See See [libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available](https://askubuntu.com/q/830466/460399)